Symfony-Mercure - Docker (https)
Good morning,
I use the Mercure image to send notifications via Symfony.
If I run everything locally, it works correctly, but if I try to deploy on a server with an associated domain, I have issues with Mercure and the SSL certificate.
My configuration is as follows:
webapp:
  image: ***/nginx
  networks:
    - default
    - reverseproxy
  volumes_from:
    - phpfpm
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: api.example.it
    LETSENCRYPT_HOST: api.example.it
    LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ***@***.it
    CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE: 48M
  restart: unless-stopped

phpfpm:
  image: image-server:latest
  volumes:
    - ./vendor:/app/vendor
    - ./resources:/app/resources
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE: 48M
    POST_MAX_SIZE: 48M

mercure:
  image: dunglas/mercure
  environment:
    SERVER_NAME: ':443'
    MERCURE_URL: 'https://api.example.it/.well-known/mercure'
    MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: 'https://api.example.it/.well-known/mercure'
    MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '***************************'
    MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '***************************'
    ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: 1
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: 'https://example.it'
    PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: '*'
    MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |-
      cors_origins "https://example.it"
      anonymous
    ADDR: ':443'
  ports:
    - '1338:443'

The error I encounter is always the following:

Dangerous site Attackers on the site you're trying to visit might
trick you into installing software or revealing things like your
password, phone, or credit card number. Chrome strongly recommends
going back to safety. Learn more Chrome has built-in safety features
to protect you while you browse — like Google Safe Browsing, which
recently found phishing on the site you're trying to visit. Phishing
sites pretend to be other sites to trick you.
Even sites that are normally safe are sometimes compromised by
attackers. Let us know if you think there's been a mistake and that
this site doesn't pose a danger.
Only visit this unsafe site if you're sure you understand the risks.

I have made many attempts, but I always end up with the error shown in the image.
Can anyone help me? I'm surely making a mistake in the container configuration, but I can't figure out where.
On the server, I use a reverse proxy, and the image also assigns the certificate to the domain present in Nginx.
Thank you very much.
My attempts have focused on the container configuration. I tried setting the address to https://api.example.it:1338 with a port, but I don't think this is correct.
I looked through the documentation but couldn't quite understand how to resolve the issue. I believe that the domain doesn't need to be re-certified, but I could be wrong.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
